# Suggest a cleaner functional way

Tags: scala, functional-programming, idioms

Here is some imperative code:

```
var sum = 0
val spacing = 6
var x = spacing
for(i <- 1 to 10) {
  sum += x * x
  x += spacing
}
```

Here are two of my attempts to "functionalize" the above code:

```
// Attempt 1
(1 to 10).foldLeft((0, 6)) {
  case((sum, x), _) => (sum + x * x, x + spacing)
}

// Attempt 2
Stream.iterate ((0, 6)) { case (sum, x) => (sum + x * x, x + spacing) }.take(11).last
```

I think there might be a cleaner and better functional way to do this. What would be that?

PS: Please note that the above is just an example code intended to illustrate the problem; it is not from the real application code.

Answer (score 7):

Replacing 10 by N, you have `spacing * spacing * N * (N + 1) * (2 * N + 1) / 6`

This is by noting that you're summing (spacing * i)^2 for the range 1..N. This sum factorizes as spacing^2 * (1^2 + 2^2 + ... + N^2), and the latter sum is well-known to be N * (N + 1) * (2 * N + 1) / 6 (see [Square Pyramidal Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number))

Comment: I would think this might be addessing the example code, rather than the real problem. Only the OP can say for sure.

Comment: No, `1+2+...+N = (N+1)*N/2`.  `1^2+2^2+...+N^2 = N*(2N+1)*(N+1)/6`, and this is not all that widely known.

Answer (score 5):

I actually like idea of lazy sequences in this case. You can split your algorithm in 2 logical steps.

At first you want to work on all natural numbers (ok.. not all, but up to max int), so you define them like this:

```
val naturals = 0 to Int.MaxValue
```

Then you need to define knowledge about how numbers, that you want to sum, can be calculated:

```
val myDoubles = (naturals by 6 tail).view map (x => x * x)
```

And putting this all together:

```
val naturals = 0 to Int.MaxValue
val myDoubles = (naturals by 6 tail).view map (x => x * x)
val mySum = myDoubles take 10 sum
```

I think it's the way mathematician will approach this problem. And because all collections are lazily evaluated - you will not get out of memory.

#### Edit

If you want to develop idea of mathematical notation further, you can actually define this implicit conversion:

```
implicit def math[T, R](f: T => R) = new {
  def ∀(range: Traversable[T]) = range.view map f
}
```

and then define `myDoubles` like this:

```
val myDoubles = ((x: Int) => x * x) ∀ (naturals by 6 tail)
```

Comment: It's just a shame that type inference breaks down when you reverse things like this...

Comment: @Kevin: Agreed... may be you know: is this already known issue (can it be eventually fixed)?

Comment: Thinking further, I'd start with `def positiveints = Iterator from 1` and take it from there - avoiding the need for any spurious `view` and `tail` methods.  There's always the potential ambiguity with natural numbers as to whether or not they should contain `0`

Comment: @Angel - Until the type of the elements has been witnessed, it's impossible to locally infer the input type of the mapping function.  Global H-M inference would help here, but doesn't play nicely with polymorphism. Solving that particular can of worms would probably earn you an honorary PhD from EPFL...

Answer (score 4):

My personal favourite would have to be:

```
val x = (6 to 60 by 6) map {x => x*x} sum
```

Or given `spacing` as an input variable:

```
val x = (spacing to 10*spacing by spacing) map {x => x*x} sum
```

or

```
val x = (1 to 10) map (spacing*) map {x => x*x} sum
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two different directions to go.  If you want to express yourself, assuming that you can't use the built-in range function (because you actually want something more complicated):

```
Iterator.iterate(spacing)(x => x+spacing).take(10).map(x => x*x).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
```

This is a very general pattern: specify what you start with and how to get the next given the previous; then take the number of items you need; then transform them somehow; then combine them into a single answer.  There are shortcuts for almost all of these in simple cases (e.g. the last fold is `sum`) but this is a way to do it generally.

But I also wonder--what is wrong with the mutable imperative approach for maximal speed?  It's really quite clear, and Scala lets you mix the two styles on purpose:

```
var x = spacing
val last = spacing*10
val sum = 0
while (x <= last) {
  sum += x*x
  x += spacing
}
```

(Note that the `for` is slower than `while` since the Scala compiler transforms `for` loops to a construct of maximum generality, not maximum speed.)

Comment: About optimizing it to maximal speed... I think Kevin Wright described it much better than I can do :) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881443/clojures-let-equivalent-in-scala/4884207#4884207

Comment: @Easy Angel - The root of much evil may be premature optimization, but the root of most of the rest is neglect of optimization.  It is much better to understand the performance characteristics of different algorithms and language constructs and choose wisely than to pretend that you never need to care and couldn't predict even if you did.  Therefore, I try to show both sides when it seems like it might be applicable (e.g. doing math).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward translation of the loop you wrote to a tail-recursive function, in an SML-like syntax.

```
val spacing = 6
fun loop (sum: int, x: int, i: int): int =
  if i > 0 then loop (sum+x*x, x+spacing, i-1)
  else sum
val sum = loop (0, spacing, 10)
```

Is this what you were looking for? (What do you mean by a "cleaner" and "better" way?)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
def toSquare(i: Int) = i * i
val spacing = 6
val spaceMultiples = (1 to 10) map (spacing *)
val squares = spaceMultiples map toSquare
println(squares.sum)
```

You have to split your code in small parts. This can improve readability a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner:

```
(0 to 10).reduceLeft((u,v)=>u + spacing*spacing*v*v)
```

Note that you need to start with 0 in order to get the correct result (else the first value 6 would be added only, but not squared).

Another option is to generate the squares first:

```
(1 to 2*10 by 2).scanLeft(0)(_+_).sum*spacing*spacing
```